# pip 20 dependencies for git repos

Tags: python, git, pip, dependencies

What is the correct way with pip 20 to set up a dependencies to a git repository?

So far, I have been following https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies
which obsoletes the dependency links.

> Warning Dependency links support has been dropped by pip starting with
>   version 19.0 (released 2019-01-22).

What is the recommended way adding a dependency on a tag or commit from a git repo reachable by http(s)?